# How can I replace an item in suspicious sand with a book that has the Mending enchantment?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to replace an item in suspicious sand from the new update with a book with a Mending enchantment but Minecraft gives me an error with my command.

Here is the code:

```
/data merge block 1102 76 2277 {item: {id:"enchanted_book, {Enchantments:[{id:\"Mending\",lvl:}"}}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your NBT data has multiple issues:

1. it seems you just copied a give command into the "id" of the item. That's not how item data nor NBT data works. It always needs to be a key:value pair. Also, the item data that doesn't describe the id or amount goes into the `tag` tag.
2. enchanted books store their enchantments in `StoredEnchantments`. So unless you literally want a book that is enchanted with Mending, you need to use that.
3. enchantment ids need to be lowercase. Enchantments also need a lvl.
4. It's always good practise to add a `Count` to your NBT data. In this case it's probably not needed, but I've included it anyways to be sure.

Here is the fixed nbt:

```
{item:{id:"minecraft:enchanted_book",Count:1b,tag:{StoredEnchantments:[{id:"minecraft:mending",lvl:1s}]}}}
```